# How to cast object if I know it's name?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have class name in string variable ***model***, so I want to cast an object to type of that loaded class ba reflection

Class name what I'am loading is "Notification" it is written in String variable ***model***

```
String model = "Notification";   
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("biznea.zredzic.pojo."+model);
```

So I have abstract class `PojoAbstract` which extends all pojo classes as it is `cls` or which really is `Notification.class`

```
public class Notification extends PojoAbstract{...}
```

And now I want to cast this to `cls` real class type *(Notification)*

```
WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE po = (WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE) gson.fromJson(json.toString(), cls);
```

I do not want to `po` be a `PojoAbstract` type I want it to be `Notification` type

I hope that I was clear :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the method [`public T cast(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) of `Class<T>`.

```
Object o = cls.cast(gson.fromJSon(json.toString(), cls));
```

But you can't assign directly to a static declaration since at compile time you won't know the type. You must keep the declaration as much non-specific as you can, since you can't assume anything at compile time.

Comment: (It might be better to say "non-specific" rather than "generic" ... because the latter term has other connotations in Java.)

Comment: So if `o` is type of Object how can I use Notification class specific methods, and I know that o is type of Notification or it isn't?

Comment: You can't invoke a method at compile time which is part of a type that is known just dynamically. This is against the strong type checker that Java has. You must invoke it through reflection. If the type is specified just at runtime, how can the type checker know that you are going to call an existent method? Mind that you are not working with an unknown type which is known to the compiler but with something that is not known at all.